# How do I change a label text when that particular label is selected using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, label

I want to update every single label I generate by using the #updatelabel input only. Let's say, I generate 3 textboxes along with labels (with incremental id) and I just would like to change the label #2 then how would I do that? Because if I choose to update label #2 then the only one that updates is label #1 and after that I can't update any other label.

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/H9mKZ/

I really need a good answer.
Thanks.

Comment: I think we need a clearer description of what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Only one element is allowed to have an ID at a time.  Instead of `$("#updatelabel")` you should use a class `$(".updatelabel")`.

Answer (score 0):

While tandu is correct about the ID property, you can always store a reference to the text box that was clicked and just you that to get the value. Here is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/H9mKZ/1/

Comment: I want to update every single label I generate by using the #updatelabel input only. Let's say, I generate 3 textboxes along with labels (with incremental id) and I just would like to change the label #2 then how would I do that? Because if I choose to update label #2 then the only one that updates is label #1 and after that I can't update any other label. Can you help me out?